# Lumen "PUT" request doesn't update

Tags: php, laravel, postman, lumen

I've the below code snippet to update a MySQL table. I'm testing my back-end with POSTMAN PUT request. This code doesn't seem to update MySQL correctly, instead it sets the MySQL cells to empty values, even though I'm getting "Updated Successfully" in my POSTMAN result.

Below is the Lumen PHP code

```
public function updateSensorPackage(Request $request, $id){
   $sensorPackage = AddSensorPackage:: find($id);
   $sensorPackage -> elderly_id = $request ->  input('elderly_id');
   $sensorPackage -> centre_id = $request -> input('centre_id'); 
   $sensorPackage -> package_id = $request -> input('package_id'); 
   $sensorPackage -> beacon_id = $request ->  input('beacon_id');
   $sensorPackage -> created_by = $request -> input('created_by'); 
   $sensorPackage -> save();
   return response('Updated Successfully', 200);
```

}

I set the POSTMAN header to "Content-type : Application/json" and sending the parameters in request body. Below I've pasted the POSTMAN "PUT" request.

[image]

After running `dd($request->all());` I got the below result

[image]

My PHP version is 7+ and Lumen version is 5.5.2

Comment: try `$sensorPackage->update();` instead

Comment: @Hussein,  not working :)

Comment: keep this change and access the properties like this `$request->elderly_id`

Comment: Does the `AddSensorPackage`'s `$fillable` property contains an array with all the fields you want to update?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova `$fillable` has to do with mass assignment, which is not his case

Comment: @Hussein yeah, thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: @IvankaTodorova can you help me with my problem

Comment: Can you do `dd($request->all())` and post the result, please?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova updated the question

Comment: Try creating a new request in new tab in POSTMAN and try again. For me POSTMAN does the exact same if I try to send mupltiple request(on different urls) in same tab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write your parameters in

```
x-www-form-urlencode
```

and see the magic, it works fine.The reason is laravel just create a feel of PUT request, it can't be given in form-data or raw data

Comment: In the case of x-www-form-urlencoded, the whole form data is sent as a long query string.

The query string contains name-value pairs separated by & character e.g. field1=value1&field2=value2 etc.

Comment: You are right, but that data is encoded so no need to worry.

Comment: Alternatively, add the values as params in your query string yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You should try sending a POST request instead of PUT, and then later add a new param like this to the request.

> _method = "PUT"

I can't remember where I found this but it has something to do with the underlying symfony request class.

EDIT: Found it.

You can also set Postman to send request parameters using 'x-www-url-formurlencoded'

https://laravel.io/forum/02-13-2014-i-can-not-get-inputs-from-a-putpatch-request

Comment: This is actually a more complete response

Answer (score 1):

Unlink get method your need to define header

```
Accept: 'application/json'
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```